# How to know filename contains other string or not in firebase cloud storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to check that uploading image name  contains `"thumb_"` or not .If filename contains  `"thumb_"` then user do not allow to upload images.
something like that :

```
 match/users/{id}/{image}{
      if:  request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*') &&
                                 request.resource.size < 1024 *1024 * 2  &&
                                 image.size()<32 &&
                                 !image.includes('thumb_')}
```

but it give error

```
Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [13], column [27]. Function not found error: Name: [includes].
```

we can not use `includes()` function in  security rule.So what should I use instead of  `includes()` ?

Comment: What is `image` in your rule?  Looks like you haven't defined it.

Comment: sir I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API documentation for security rules for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#string), there is no method called "includes" on string data.  You can see there is a method called "matches" which lets you perform regular expression matching on strings.  To see if the string in `image` contains the string "thumb_":

```
image.matches('thumb_')
```